# How to delete Files via Developer Console

Tags: apex, files

Is there an easy way to delete all files via Apex - developer console?

Something like `delete [select id from File];`

Answer (score 2):

You need to request ContentDocument in SOQL, not File:

```
delete [SELECT Id FROM ContentDocument];
```